# Puma prints huge unruly output in terminal and runs slowly in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, server, puma

What is going on with this dump when I am running Puma for my Rails server in development. I find my app starts being really slow in development and I have to restart the server every once and a while. So I'm curious about what is going on with this dump and how can I make my Puma server act better in development?

[image: Dump]

This is my Procfile

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

This is my Puma.rb file

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 8)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Comment: you haven't said anything about how exactly you're running puma (other than 'in development'). If you're not more specific, I'm not sure how easy it will be to help you.

Comment: I added more information. Let me know what else might help.